# How to let variable in useEffect stay?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

"Assignments to the 'Name' variable from inside React Hook useEffect will be lost after each render. To preserve the value over time, store it in a useRef Hook and keep the mutable value in the '.current' property. Otherwise, you can move this variable directly inside useEffect  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps" This warning is displayed in the console and I don't know why. Also the handleLogin is not setting value.

```
function Home(handleLogin) {

  let Name = '';
  useEffect(() => {
    try{
      Name = (location.state.name || location.state.Username);
      handleLogin.handleLogin(true);
    } catch(err) {
      Name = 'You Need To Login First !!!'
      handleLogin.handleLogin(false);
    }
  }, []); // Tried [Name], [Name, handleLogin] too
}
```

Comment: What is the `Name` variable used for? If you're trying to put this text on the screen, then make name a state, as in `const [Name, setName] = useState('')`. That way you can set state and re-render the component.

Comment: You should also use State for handleLogin, with something like: const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState("handleLogin.handleLogin")

Comment: I replaced the `Name` to useState variable and also changed the it as `setName(props.details.name)`, it run perfectly until I refresh the page. It sets the `setName` to undefined but the `handleLogin` remains true. How to retain the name even after **refreshing the page**, and how to throw an `err` if it is **undefined**. @NicholasTower @GordonMaloney

Answer (score 3):

Like the error states, you either need to store Name inside a `useRef()` and access it via that or alternatively as state via `useState()`. If the `Name` variable is used for render purposes (you show it somewhere inside your React component), you'll most likely want to tie this to state as such:

```js
function Home(handleLogin) {
  const [Name, setName] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      setName(location.state.name || location.state.Username);
      handleLogin.handleLogin(true);
    } catch(err) {
      setName('You Need To Login First !!!');
      handleLogin.handleLogin(false);
    }
  }, []);
}
```

If the `Name` variable does not need to be rendered anywhere, you can instead use a ref to prevent the component from re-rendering when you set `Name`:

```js
function Home(handleLogin) {
  const Name = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      Name.current = (location.state.name || location.state.Username);
      handleLogin.handleLogin(true);
    } catch(err) {
      Name.current = 'You Need To Login First !!!';
      handleLogin.handleLogin(false);
    }
  }, []);
}
```

Given your error string, it looks like this is being rendered somewhere so I'd go with the first approach.

As for your second question, we'd need to see what props you're passing down to a `Home` component as well as the logic of the parent component in order to properly answer it.